# C# .NET Call Master Page Method from Content Page in HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my Site.Master Page (SiteMaster) I have the following code:

```
public string RandomString()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat("ABCEFG", 10)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}
```

this should give me a random string. 
Now in my ContentPage.aspx I want to call this function the same time as Im trying to import a Js File so first I imported the MasterType on top of the page like this:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>
```

and then import my js script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Custom/myJSFILE.js?rndstr=<%= Master.RandomString(); %>"></script>
```

But if I try to run it I get the following error:

> Error compiling a resource needed to handle this request. Review the following specific error details and change the source code accordingly.
>
> Compiler error message: CS1026:) expected

But somehow If I do the same in the MasterSite.aspx file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Custom/myJSFILE.js?rndstr=<%# RandomString() %>"></script>
```

It works like a charm. So how can I call the same function in my Content pages aswell?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the Master page directly, you need to create a property of it, and use that to access the methods. `Site1` is the class name of the Master page (`public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage`)

```
public Site1 MyMaster;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMaster = (Site1)Page.Master;
}
```

And then you have access in the aspx

```
<%= MyMaster.RandomString() %>
```

Comment: thanks for this. Now I dont get any Error anymore, but somehow it doesnt return me a random string. its just `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Custom/myJSFILE.js?rndstr=` instead of `<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Custom/myJSFILE.js?rndstr=ABCDEFG` like the others have?

Comment: It's working here. I get a random string on the aspx page.